# How can I register my webapp in CAS services management?

Tags: service, server, cas

My School want to implement a CAS service, I did the most of the configuration, but I need to register the webapp, How can I register the webapp in CAS services management? Or if you have some samples that can help me, I'll be really grateful.

Comment: Please share the configuration you did in CAS to get more insight on the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using cas management app is version 4.2.x.  I am not sure what version you are trying to use.

Although I was able to build the cas management app successfully and make it up and running, for some reason configuring the service in this management app did not work for me.

Alternatively, I found another way to make it for work me. You can register your apps in a JSON file in your cas server web application (note: Not the cas management webapp) itself in the following location, /WEB-INF/classes/services

Follow the following steps,

- You will see default services in this location. Copy and create a new json file for your service.
- The file name is made up of service Name and unique id (you can choose a unique id of your choice)
- Inside the file, you need to configure the service URL, id that you gave in the file name, name of the service application, logout service url, etc...)
- restart the cas server. Service should be ready for use

Comment: Thank you man, could you give me an example about how to configure the service, please? I am just learning about this, for that reason I dont know how to do that. I have implemented a CAS 5.1.x

Comment: @BERNABÉARAGÓN the following link gives a pretty good explanation. Let me know if this helps, https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/JSON-Service-Management.html. If not, I can try helping you further.

Comment: it would help to understand what all steps you did so far and what error messages you are seeing? I would also recommend you to post in the google cas google groups community, https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/forum/#!forum/cas-dev

Comment: Hello, I have one question, the web applications of my University are not Https, just http. Is there a possibility to make work the cas server with http? Can we talk in private? I really need help please.

Comment: To my knowledge, cas can be run only on https. I beleive that is one of the key reasons for CAS to be secure. If you can share the configuration details  here (in limited form), I could be able to help you.